# Will you greet your close friend 'Hi there'?

Tags: usage, conversation, greetings, email

I thought 'Hi there' was only used to greet people who you didn't know their names, such as you write a complaint letter to customer service. So I feel a little bit awkward when I received messages with 'Hi there' + some random chat/information from my close friends. I have encountered twice such case. Not sure if I have been overreacting on these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There" suggests a physical space/place.

You are at your desk. You're busy working and then look up and see a friend or acquaintance whom you only just noticed or were not expecting.
You say: "Hi there".

It is informal. It does not mean you don't know the person. **In fact, you might know them very well**. Or you are at your desk at home, and your child comes up unexpectedly, and you say: "Hi there."

**It is not appropriate for writing emails to customer service.** So, feeling uncomfortable receiving an email with that great as a customer service person is completely understandable...

There is also an element of surprise. You were not expecting the person to show up unexpectedly and it pleases  you.

Comment: 'Hi there' would be a very informal way to address a communication to an unknown person. A more formal way would be 'Dear Sir/Madam', 'Dear Customer Services' or similar.

Comment: @KateBunting I disagree. I never say Hi There to people I don't know and e-mails that contain that to me when I don't know the person are usually scams. If one writes to customer service, one can just say Hello to be informal.

Comment: I wasn't recommending it, just saying that if you _did_  use it in those circumstances, it would sound _extremely_ informal.

Comment: @KateBunting How is: very informal, your term, and mine, inappropriate any different when I specifically pointed out it was informal?? Your comment adds little beyond what I have already said.

Comment: You said 'I disagree' as though you had understood my comment as recommending 'Hi there' as an email salutation, which I had certainly not intended to do.

Comment: @KateBunting Since I think it is totally inappropriate because of the informality, I would not use the explanation: would be very informal. It's not that it *would be* very informal, it is informal and therefore inappropriate and your comment does not add anything to my answer.